# GMicrosoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException while downloading a file from datalake store in azure?

Tags: file, azure, exception, download

I am getting the Rest Exception as mentioned

```
DownloadFile(@"/catalog/CSV1.txt", "C:\\Users\\samda\\Desktop\\CSV1.txt");

public static void DownloadFile(string srcPath, string destPath)
        {
            var stream = _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Open(_adlsAccountName, srcPath);
            var fileStream = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create);

            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I am calling the above download function in my console application  DownloadFile(@"/catalog/CSV1.txt", "C:\\Users\\samda\\Desktop\\CSV1.txt"); but on the filesystem.open method it is giving Rest Exception .I already have access in the datalake store

Comment: I checked the fiddler logs on the line where exception is occurring it is stating:{"RemoteException":{"exception":"AccessControlException","message":"OPEN failed with error 0x83090aa2 (Forbidden. ACL verification failed. Either the resource does not exist or the user is not authorized to perform the requested operation.).